# Intellij não abre APK depois da instalação

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij

No meu aplicativo, depois de instalar , o Intellij não "manda" abrir o apk.

No meu manifest já está configurado a Activity principal

```
<application 
...
    <activity
        android:name=".Activitys.Main"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
...
```

Aparentemente no Intellij está correto a configuração do "build"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei trocar esta opção, escolhendo manualmente a activity.. mas não funcionou.. apenas instala o APK, mas não abre.. tenho que ir manualmente lá na opção para abrir...

Com isto tenho problema na hora de debugar a classe `Application`

Alguém pode ter idéia do que pode estar ocorrendo? Já reiniciei o Android e o PC também..

[Editado]

Hoje apareceu o seguinte erro ao tentar instalar:

```
Error while executing: am startservice meu.pacote/com.android.tools.fd.runtime.InstantRunService
Starting service: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=meu.pacote/com.android.tools.fd.runtime.InstantRunService }
Error: Not found; no service started.
```

Com essa informação desabilitei o InstantRun, e app começou a abrir normal, mas de qualquer modo.. Gostaria de deixar habilitado o Instant Run, se alguém tiver alguma idéia de como resolver isto...

Answer (score 0):

Verifique ao lado do botão Run se você está com a opção 'app' selecionada também. Se não ele vai tentar rodar onde está a seleção na aba 'Project'

Pelo seu Edit parece que não encontra a classe principal, abra o AndoridManifest posicione seu cursor no nome da classe principal ".Activityes.Main" e pressione Ctrl+B para navegar pra ela, se nao encontrar voce declarou o pacote errado.

E outra coisa, nome de pacote começam com letra minuscula, e nomes de componentes que extenderam do Android usam o sufixo do tipo no nome da classe: "MainActivity".

Comment: Sim está com a opção `app` selecionada

Comment: Editei a resposta.